# Problem with Django site on a shared hosting

Tags: python, django, hosting, shared

I have a problem when i try to install a Django website, on a Mocha hosting, and their technical support is so much uninformed... (I strongly don't recomment Mocha hosting for a django hosting)
They have mod_wsgi support, and mod_python installed, but when i am uploading the site as in their tutorial 
 http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=448&nav=0,46
but at the end i am getting an error like:
          Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1202, in _process_target
    module = import_module(module_name, path=path)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 304, in import_module
    return **import**(module_name, {}, {}, ['*'])

**ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.modpython**

I know this issue has been treated here as well: [Error while deploying Django on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673936/error-while-deploying-django-on-apache)

But i don't have access to the terminal, how can i solve it? Is there a way to correctly set the python path without terminal access?
Thanks!

Comment: mod_python is dead. Consider using mod_wsgi.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but ive used webfaction for django hosting and it is awesome. the support is great and they have django preinstalled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you double check that you upload a django in

> /home/youraccount/webapps/django

Most likely the hosting provieder has harcode (width you account) 
that path in the apache configuration for the mod_python approach.

Or

Why don't you use mod_wsgi and in the wsgi script  add your django, like this.

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/youraccount/webapps/django') # Path to your custom django.
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings' 
application = WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that article, it seems that they don't provide Django for your use. You'll need to upload it as well.

Comment: yes... though at first they said they actually provide Django... i am confused.. and dissapointed.. i hope i will find a way to make it work, though..